# Bounce the Downloads stack dock icon using C++ (without using ObjectiveC)

Tags: cocoa, macos, firefox

Firefox doesn't currently [bounce the Downloads box in the dock when a download is finished](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=402520), like Safari, Chrome and Camino do.

If Firefox was written in Objective C, you could very easily add the [one line of Objective C code](http://13bold.com/quick-tricks/bouncing-the-downloads-stack/) required to do this.  However, it's not.  Is there a way to call this Cocoa function from C++ so that it can be added to Firefox for the benefit of all Mac users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Carbon API's *CFNotificationCenterPostNotification*.
Carbon is pure C.

Documentation and code samples [here](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/Tasks/Communication.html).

Comment: I thought Carbon was going the way of the Dodo. In fact, using Carbon locks you out of 64 bit. 

I notice that you mention CFNotificationCenterPostNotification, though, which looks like a Core Foundation class. That might be OK.

Comment: Yes, it's not Carbon. Core Foundation, Core Services, and a few other frameworks that *can be* accessed through the Carbon framework are available in 64-bit. In fact, even some parts of Carbon (e.g., Carbon Event Manager) are available in 64-bit.

Answer (score 4):

What I'd recommend, and I had to do this for a project I was working on, you could have a few files of obj-c++ that provide both a C/C++ api and internally use obj-c code to trigger the doc flashing.

Essentially you create a standard C/C++ header file.  In the code side you make the file a .m or .mm file.

This would then let you write the obj-c one liner in questions directly into a C/C++ function, and since the header file is in plain C/C++ it won't be a compiler error for the non .mm files in the project.

This of course assumes that compiling with a compiler (like GCC) that speaks both languages.

A simple and (tested) example of this approach would be:

TriggerBounce.h

```
void TriggerBounce(char * filepath);
```

TriggerBounce.m

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

void TriggerBounce(char * filepath) {
    NSString *pathToFile = [NSString stringWithCString:filepath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"com.apple.DownloadFileFinished" object:pathToFile]; 
}
```